# Сложный запрос(процедура)

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Есть необходимость создать сложный запрос(процедуру). Разницы нет. Есть 2 таблицы связанные ключом. `journal_field_data` с ключом `journal_record_id` и `Journal_Records` с ключом `id`. Так же в `Journal_Records` есть ключ `JOURNAL_ID` и `JOURNAL_TABLE_ID`. Суть самой задачи в том что в html коде есть таблица, с вложенной в ней таблицей. Мне понадобилось часть полей из вложенной таблицы вытащить в основную. Для того что я бы я мог просматривать ранее внесённые данные мне нужно в базе переписать старые данные в новые поля. Я пока что додумался как сделать 2 выборки для условий итогового запроса(процедуры). Вот как я делаю:

```
select * from journal_field_data where journal_record_id in
(select id from Journal_Records where journal_id = 10286 and journal_table_id = 1001)

select * from journal_field_data where journal_record_id in
(select id from Journal_Records where journal_id = 10286 and journal_table_id = 1)
```

Первым запросом я выбираю данные вложенной таблицы как она выглядела раньше. И мне нужно у части записей (основываясь на условии по полю `FIELD_NAME`) сменить `journal_record_id` на нужный `journal_record_id` из второго приведённого мной запроса. Пока что не пойму как это сделать. Алгоритм сложный. То что я описал вообще можно реализовать. Если да то кто знает подскажите как это можно сделать. Буду очень благодарен если будут примеры. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: На SQL можно сделать все. А на ваш вопрос ответить  практически не реально, потому что не понятно что и на что надо заменять. могу только подозревать, что journal_record_id надо заменить на соответствующий ему (по не ясным критериям) взятым из каких то записей с table_id=1. Лучше приведите полную структуру используемых таблиц (и не текстом в свободной форме, а виде create table) и образце текущих данных и что на основе этих данных должно быть заменено

Comment: Я так понимаю, два запроса - это "как есть" и "как надо". Результат каждого из них - это некоторый набор строк. Пока по вашему вопросу непонятно, по какому принципу надо сопоставлять друг с другом строки из этих запросов.